# Sending a message from webpage to webcontrol

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Goal:
Display a message in the Webcontrol. The message's will be started in the default.aspx

Problem:

> I don't know how to send a message (string test = "testing testing")
>   from Default.aspx to the WebUserControl.ascx by using C# code

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<%@ Register Tagprefix="Acme" Tagname="AdRotator" Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">


    <Acme:AdRotator id="Control1" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>


namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl1" %>



namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }
    }
}
```

// Fullmetalboy

Comment: ?! can you show markup and explain better what you mean by sending instances in this scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand the question. You can expose a public property on the Bag control that lets you set/get the Coffee instance.

If you don't have a direct handle to the Bag control you can always pass it in the current HttpContext [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) cache.

However if you *really* want to move to loose coupling and dependency injection then implement the MVP pattern in WebForms.

Edit: Based on your updated question add a property to your webcontrol like this.

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string MyProperty
    {
       get;set;
    }
}
```

Then set the property from the page like this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control1.MyProperty = "Testing Testing";
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
<Acme:AdRotator id="Control1" runat="server" MyProperty="Testing Testing" />
```